# Getting min and max values from Thinking Sphinx search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

How can I get min and max values from Thinking Sphinx search by column Price?

```
indexes :price
indexes :name, :sortable => true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look to http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-2.0.7.html#api-func-setselect

with sphinxQL it's possible

With SphinxSE be carefull, you can join real data and compute...